# Blender Particle % amount not rendering as expected

Tags: rendering, particles

This is what i want rendered whit particle amount in 17%
[image]

but when i render it the viewport display full amount of particles 100%

[image]

its possible to render what i'am seeing with 17% particles amount ? i'am using hair system to render flowers

Answer (score 0):

The value you show is under *Viewport Display* so it won't change the amount for render. I can't see any amount for render, except *Emission > Number* of course. There is a *Display Amount* and a *Render Amount* under *Children* though, if you ever want to use children.